# Email content exceeds width of screen

Tags: php, html, css

I have a php Mailer email in which I am styling the html email. Everything is correct except my content within `#email-header` exceeds the width of the screen. I am not sure why because I set the `max-width` to 600px.

Does anyone see anything I am doing wrong which would be causing this?

```
$mail2->Body    = '
            <body>
                <div id="header-background" style="background:#16597B;width:100%;max-width:100%;height:auto;">
                    <div id="email-header" style="width:600px;max-width:600px;height:auto;margin:auto;display:block;padding:20px 8px;">
                        <div id="logo"><a href=""><img src="" style="width:200px;height:auto;text-align:center" alt=""></a></div>
                        <div style="clear:both;"></div>
                        <div id="email-to" style="color:#FFF;font-family:Helvetica Neue,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;font-weight:bold;font-size: 2em;margin-top:35px;">Hi '.$consult_name.',</div>
                            <div id="email-header-description" style="font-family:Helvetica Neue,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;font-size:1.3em;color:#d0dde4;margin-top:45px;">
                                <p style="font-size:1.3em;">Thanks for wanting to work with us!</p>
                                <p>We received your consultation inquiry. Here shortly your information will be reviewed and we will be in touch with you as soon as possible to schedule your consultation.</p><br>
                                <p>Thanks again!</p><br>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </body>
        ';
```

Comment: Your above code is fine -- it doesn't escape the bounds on windows greater than 600px. Are you sure that your client has a panel wider than 600px?

Comment: The email client (gmail) is creating a sidebar and I have to scroll over to see the content.

Comment: The only thing I can see is that you have one more closing `</div>` than you should. But even with that, your text doesn't appear to overflow -- https://jsfiddle.net/sua9tj06/

Comment: @ObsidianAge It is still doing it. I am viewing this on a phone viewport. I thought that 600px was a safe `max-width` for all devices?

Comment: 600px is a bit high for most phones; many are only 320px. The Samsung E3210 is only 128px! I'd recommend a 'safe' size of 300px, and also recommend checking out [**ViewportSizes**](http://viewportsizes.com). You've also got a **hard-coded** `width` of 600px in addition to the `max-width`. Simply removing that should allow correct word-wrap on devices less than 600px :)

Comment: @ObsidianAge That was it. Thanks! Feel free to leave an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you have a fixed width of `600px` in addition to your `max-width` of 600px. Simply removing the fixed `width` should fix your word-wrap problem.

Note that 600px is a rather high breakpoint for mobile phones, as many phones have a [**display below this**](http://www.viewportsizes.com). I'd recommend `300px` to cover most devices.

Also note that you have an additional closing `</div>`, which may cause some clients to play up a little.

Here's updated code that fixes both of these issues:

```
$mail2->Body = '
<body>
  <div id="header-background" style="background:#16597B;width:100%;max-width:100%;height:auto;">
    <div id="email-header" style="max-width:600px;height:auto;margin:auto;display:block;padding:20px 8px;">
      <div id="logo">
        <a href=""><img src="http://placehold.it/100" style="width:200px;height:auto;text-align:center" alt=""></a>
      </div>
      <div style="clear:both;"></div>
      <div id="email-to" style="color:#FFF;font-family:Helvetica Neue,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;font-weight:bold;font-size: 2em;margin-top:35px;">Hi '.$consult_name.',</div>
      <div id="email-header-description" style="font-family:Helvetica Neue,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;font-size:1.3em;color:#d0dde4;margin-top:45px;">
        <p style="font-size:1.3em;">Thanks for wanting to work with us!</p>
        <p>We received your consultation inquiry. Here shortly your information will be reviewed and we will be in touch with you as soon as possible to schedule your consultation.</p>
        <br>
        <p>Thanks again!</p>
        <br>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
';
```

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: Thanks again for the help!